# Getting a JSON response with requests and ArcGIS REST API

Tags: python, arcgis-online, json

I'm performing a batch download from my AGOL account, and using the [ESRI documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Export_Item/02r30000008s000000/) `export item` I can export content to shapefiles.  I would like to then download the newly created shapefiles.  In order to accomplish this I have to be able to have the ID number of the newly created shapefile.  According to the documentation it is in the JSON response.

sudo code:

```
import requests
import arcrest
import json

exporturl = self.root_url +'/users/' + self.username + '/export'
export = requests.post(exporturl, params=FsParams)
export_response = export.json()
```

What I have tried:

```
response = export_response['exportItemId']
print response
```

Error:  `KeyError: 'exportItemId'`

printing `response = export_response` returns the `params` from the `post`

Using the `requests` library can I access the JSON response?  If this is not possible with `requests` what method will work?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what `export_response` and `export` prints out? Based on your code (looking at it, not trying it), if your URL is correct you should be getting a response.However, a guess might be your syntax of `export.json()` is wrong, it should be `export_respone =json.loads(export)` (but just a guess as I stopped using *requests*

Comment: I know that it is not `json.loads()`  as that does not work.  I modified the the OP with the error

Comment: Error is good: its saying the response you got back doesn't have that value in it. do a `print export_response` and see all the key:values. This will tell you either your initial request is wrong, or hopefully something useful to help you debug in the returned response

Comment: @KHibma your suggestion of printing `export_response` exposed an issue with my first two layers.  `response = export_response['exportItemId']` worked once I put it in a `try` clause.  If you move that to an answer Ill accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code, as posted, is correct when working with `requests` and `json`.
As indicated from the comments, when making a request over multiple items, you might get a different response back depending on what the original item was requested against.

The error in question, `KeyError: 'exportItemId'` comes from the fact the response returned a dictionary without the `exportItemId` key and you tried to access it. There are multiple ways to handle this. A simple `try` / `except` as you indicate will allow you to pass over instances when you dont get back a key which you were expecting. Alternatively you could do an explicit check that the key exists in the dictionary before attempting to access it.